# Place SVG element over img tag

Tags: javascript, svg

How to place svg element(rect, circle, etc.,) over  html. This is my coding. can anyone help.

```
<div id="myImgId" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background:#000;" onmousedown="doSomething()" onmouseup="return false;">
<img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
<svg id="svgOne" y="200" width="200" height="200"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nsgch/

```
<div id="myImgId" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background:#000;" onmousedown="doSomething()" onmouseup="return false;">
   <img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="position:absolute;"/>

   <svg id="svgOne" y="200" width="200" height="200" style="position:absolute; left:90px; top:90px;">
      <path fill="#014da2" d="M16,1.466C7.973,1.466,1.466,7.973,1.466,16C1.466,24.027,7.973,30.534,16,30.534C24.027,30.534,30.534,24.027,30.534,15.999999999999998C30.534,7.973,24.027,1.466,16,1.466Z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give the elements a style of position: fixed or position: absolute depending on your needs.

```
<div id="myImgId" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background:#000;" onmousedown="doSomething()" onmouseup="return false;">
<img style="position:fixed;" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/005/cache/domestic-cat_516_600x450.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <svg style="position:fixed;top:50px" id="svgOne" width="200" height="200"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/></svg>
</div>
```

Note that the x and y attributes of outer `<svg>` elements are ignored. You'd need to use top and left styles to position it just as you would a html element.